# How to change default layout in express using handlebars?

Tags: node.js, express, handlebars.js

I am using Express 4.9.0 and express-generator.

Created boilerplate with a following command:

```
express --hbs projectname
```

Builtin handlebars is using `views/layout.hbs` by default as a master page. But i cannot see any settings in my app.js to change that behaviour.

piece of code from my app.js:

```
// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'hbs');
```

1. How can i change my default layout globally?
2. What if i want to have 2 or 3 different global layouts?

Comment: i want to thank you Heihachi for putting up this question, i was searching for a way to integrate handlebars w/Express but couldn't find a good example, looking at the express-generator commandline, made me recollect how hbs can be used, and gave me a simple yet good demo that i couldn't find online. Thanks.

Answer (score 134, accepted):

You can specify what layout you want to use as part of the render call. If you create a new layout called `other.hbs`, you can then do something like:

```
res.render('view', { title: 'my other page', layout: 'other' });
```

To override this for the entire application, you can use:

```
app.set('view options', { layout: 'other' });
```

Comment: Thanks, but can't i do that globally?

Comment: @Heihachi I have updated the answer to include a global option.

Comment: that's it! If i want few more global layouts i'll just duplicate a line with app.set(), right?

Comment: How are you going to have multiple global layouts? How will your views know which global layout to use?

Comment: Late to the party but is it something that comes default in `express` or is this a `hbs` thing? Because, I don't see any reference to `layout.hbs` either in `app.js` or in `routers/index.js`.

Comment: Nevermind, I found it. It's a `hbs` thing. If not specified it [automatically](https://github.com/donpark/hbs/blob/master/lib/hbs.js#L115) sets the layout to `layout`.  
On line 115:-  
 
`var layout_filename = path.join(view_dir, layout || 'layout');`

Comment: @TimothyStrimple just wondering, what if the data i want to send to the view includes the property called layout and i want to use res.render() to inherit a specific layout. multiple global layouts could be handy in a case where i want different assets and headers/footers/sidebars in different sections of the site. i could send JSON data to the layout view to do that, but then i wont be sending pure data to the view.

Comment: I had to google for a long time to find this answer.  Thanks, wish it was more clear in the docs.

Comment: thanks, it works.but, i got another question, how did u know to set "view options", i cant find the reference in expressjs website.

Comment: Horrible design choice to mix representational variables like that with the other variables...

Comment: this is actually deprecated from express 4, it's just a handlebars thing.

Answer (score 16):

From the handlebars readme:

> There are two ways to set a default layout: configuring the view engine's defaultLayout property, or setting Express locals app.locals.layout.
>
> The layout into which a view should be rendered can be overridden per-request by assigning a different value to the layout request local. The following will render the "home" view with no layout:
>
> ```
> app.get('/', function (req, res, next) {
>    res.render('home', {layout: false});
> });
> ```

In case you want to set the default layout just for a specific subroute, you might wanna use the following in the top section of your route:

```
router.all('/*', function (req, res, next) {
    req.app.locals.layout = 'admin'; // set your layout here
    next(); // pass control to the next handler
    });
```

You can also set the default layout on initialization:

```
// Create `ExpressHandlebars` instance with a default layout.
var hbs = exphbs.create({
    defaultLayout: 'main',
    helpers      : helpers,

    // Uses multiple partials dirs, templates in "shared/templates/" are shared
    // with the client-side of the app (see below).
    partialsDir: [
        'shared/templates/',
        'views/partials/'
        ]
    });

// Register `hbs` as our view engine using its bound `engine()` function.
app.engine('handlebars', hbs.engine);
app.set('view engine', 'handlebars');
```

Comment: `app.engine('hbs', hbs.engine);
app.set('view engine', 'hbs');`
on doing this in the exact same line , my page says: 
**Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/home/ray/Desktop/phoneSkill/functions/views/layouts/main.handlebars'**
I wonder why it is happening ?
But when i set  `var hbs = exphbs.create({
    defaultLayout: 'main.hbs', ...` in the exact same line it works and show me the pages. I wonder why this is happening ? shouldnot it be able to parse main.hbs automatically. ?

Comment: @Coderboi set `extname: 'hbs'` in config to modify default extension name. Example: `var hbs = exphbs.create({ defaultLayout: 'main',  extname: 'hbs', ...`

Comment: doesnt work for me in 22

Answer (score 6):

This should work now..

```
npm install express-handlebars

.
├── app.js
└── views
    ├── home.handlebars
    └── layouts
        └── main.handlebars

2 directories, 3 files
```

app.js

```
var express = require('express');
var exphbs  = require('express-handlebars');

var app = express();

app.engine('handlebars', exphbs({defaultLayout: 'main'}));
app.set('view engine', 'handlebars');

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.render('home');
});

app.listen(3000);
```

views/layouts/main.handlebars:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Example App</title>
</head>
<body>

    {{{body}}}

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: When I try this i get: ReferenceError: exphbs is not defined

Comment: You might miss this line in your code..

var exphbs  = require('express-handlebars');

Comment: Yes. I thought installing it using express install ... would import it automatically. Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

I hope you are using `express-handlebars`. This instructions are for express-handlebars. For `hbs`, procedures are little different.

Step-1: Require handlebars

```
const exphbs = require('express-handlebars');
```

step-2: Register handlebars template engine. while registering, you can configure

for changing layout directory

```
const layoutPath = path.join(__dirname, './templates/layouts'); //you can build your desired path
app.engine('handlebars', exphbs({ layoutsDir: layoutPath }));
```

other available options along with layoutsDir are

```
interface ExphbsOptions {
    handlebars?: any;
    extname?: string;
    layoutsDir?: string;
    partialsDir?: any;
    defaultLayout?: string;
    helpers?: any;
    compilerOptions?: any;
}
```

step-3: If you want to change views directory

```
const viewPath = path.join(__dirname, './templates/views');
app.set('views', viewPath);
```

step-4: For some template, If you don't wish to give layout, you have to specify as `layout: false` . Otherwise app will crash. You can configure as follow, if you need.

```
app.get('/', (req, res, next) => {
    res.render('shop', { title: 'My Shop', layout: false })
});
```

[For more info about express-handlebars](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-handlebars)

Answer (score 2):

If you're using the 'express-handlebars' module, then the following should work:

```
// ...
app.set("views", __dirname );

exphbs.ExpressHandlebars.prototype.layoutsDir = 'path/to/directory/';
app.engine('handlebars', exphbs({defaultView: 'name-of-template'}));

// ...
```

I came to this by digging around in the module's source, it turns out that this line...

```
// express-handlebars/lib/express-handlebars.js (line 55 in v1.2.2)
ExpressHandlebars.prototype.layoutsDir  = 'views/layouts/';
```

...is what gives the default behaviour of always looking in '{{whatever you specified}}/views/layouts/'

So essentially - if, perhaps, you have a different dir structure in mind or have some other reason to override it, you can by using the line in my example. Just be sure that you do this **before** you instantiate **exphbs**.

If you're using some other module (I'm not sure which are out there) it's likely that they have some similar setting that can be overridden with a bit of jiggery-pokery (just run a 'find' on the file contents for 'views/layouts/'.

note that I am leaving 'app.set("views", __dirname );' as is so that I keep templates anywhere in my server directory and render them like so:

```
res.render("moduleName/templateName");
```

After updating to v2.0.1 The above won't work, instead you can pass the default directory in as an argument as below:

```
var hbs = exphbs.create({
  layoutsDir: 'app/server/',
  ...
```