# Express 4 handlebars render without layout

Tags: node.js, express, handlebars.js

Is there a way in an express 4 app to render a view without using a layout?

I have a layout.hbs inside the project. The file seems to be used without needing to register it anywhere and for most views that is ok, but what if just a single view needs to be rendered without?

Answer (score 58, accepted):

Assuming you are using express-handlebars you can specify a different layout from your route/controller when you call the render method. To get rid of the layout altogether you can set the layout to `false`.

```
router.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.render('home', {layout: false});
});
```

https://github.com/ericf/express-handlebars#layouts

Comment: Actually I was using the default package hbs that comes from the express generator but I'll give this a try. Thanks

Comment: and could someone pass some context to the view at this point? i can't find a way to deactivate the layout and pass some context. for ex, router.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.render('home', {layout: false}, data);
});

Comment: Yeah you just add your data to the same object that has `layout:false`. Like this: `router.get('/', function(req, res) { res.render('home', {layout: false, data: data}); });`

Comment: @Ryan, yes, but it should be more clear in your answer that `data` is not an object but merely a variable

Comment: I need same solution for nestjs, there are decorator @Render. Which expect 1 argument.
For example, how to disable layout here:

```
  @Render('landing/index')
```

Answer (score 1):

It should be clear, when you have data to render, that the `layout` should be merely an extra property of such data

```
var data = {
    layout: false, 
    var1: var1,
    var2: var2
};

res.render('home', data);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't wish to give layout, you have to specify as `layout: false` . Otherwise app will crash. You can configure as follow, if you need.

```
app.get('/', (req, res, next) => {
    res.render('shop', { title: 'My Shop', layout: false })
});
```

[For more congiguration of express-handlebars](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59926168/10907720)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `app.render()` function to render html.
You are good to go with [Rayan's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30468818/7135309).
As on the [express documentation](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#app.render) itself mentions that, `res.render()` method also uses `app.render()` method under the hood.

```js
const app = require('express')();
app.set('view engine', 'hbs');
```

```js
/**
 * Render email template with data
 * 
 * @param {String} emailTemplate email template path
 * @param {Object} renderParams Render parameters
 * @return {Promise} rendered template
 */
async function renderEmail(emailTemplate, renderParams) {
 const renderParams = { layout: false, ...otherRenderParams };

 return await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
   app.render(emailTemplate, renderParams, function (err, html) {
       if (err) return reject(err);
       return resolve(html);
   });
 });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

this worked for me to have 1 page without the `main.handlebars` layout:

1. add layout false to the data object:

```
object.layout=false;
```

2. render

```
res.render('page', object);
```

adding `.layout` to the existing object allows you to easily still pass the object data.