# How to set handlebars layout directory?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, handlebars.js

This is my `nodejs express` setup for view and directories using handlebars:

```
- server.js
- routes
    |-- index.js
-config
    |-- config.js
- client
    |-- public
    |     | -- js
    |     | -- css
    |     | -- font
    |-- views
         |-- index.html
         |-- layout
              |-- layout.handlebars
    | ... other directories
```

And here is my node.js code:

```
// Set static folder
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/client/public')));
// Views and view engine
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, '/client/views'));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.engine('html', handlebars({ defaultLayout: 'layout' }));
```

Handlebars is not being able to find my layout. Its looking at the `app/views/layouts/layout.handlebars`, but it should be looking at `app/client/views/layouts/layout.handlebars`

What am I missing here ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to change default layout in express using handlebars?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26871522/how-to-change-default-layout-in-express-using-handlebars)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Seems like you are using [express-handlebars](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-handlebars)

You need to point the directories while creating an instance of it.

```
const hbs = exphbs.create({
    extname      :'hbs',
    layoutsDir   : 'path/to/layout/directory',
    defaultLayout: 'main',
    helpers      : 'path/to/helpers/directory',
    partialsDir  : [
        'path/to/partials/directory'
    ]
});
```

If you don't initiate it with custom folder locations, it looks up for the files in the default locations.

Also, the view engine needs to be set as `hbs.engine` not `ejs`

```
app.engine('hbs', hbs.engine);
app.set('view engine', 'hbs');
```

Comment: Does partialsDir mean `views/` directory? But the default layoutsDir is `views/layouts` right?