# Why is app.engine not defaulting to layout.hbs as a default

Tags: node.js, express, controller, handlebars.js

I created a style format with the layout.hbs and notice that all of the pages are not sharing the same consistency in style. I have noticed that I did not declare an app. engine within the app.js. Next, I implemented the app.engine   code to set the default layout that is implemented within the layout.hbs

```
app.engine('hbs', hbs ({extname: 'hbs',defaultLayout: 'layout'}));
```

An error occurred stating that the layout.hbs cannot be located. I implemented  the code again as I noticed I did not direct the folders directories to the layout .hbs. So I implemented the code to

```
app.engine('hbs', hbs ({extname: 'hbs',defaultLayout: 'layout', layoutsDir:__dirname + '/app_server/views'}));
```

And the error has disappeared and the default layout structure that has been set to layout.hbs is only showing on the local server index and not the same throughout all of the controllers. I am not too sure what else I am missing

**controller and routes code**

```
var express = require('express');
var exphbs = require('express-handlebars');
var router = express.Router();
var ctrlCaribbeanIslands = require('../controllers/CaribbeanIslands')



/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', ctrlCaribbeanIslands.login);
router.get('/blog/add',ctrlCaribbeanIslands.addPost);
router.get('/chat/add',ctrlCaribbeanIslands.addChat);
router.get('/review/add',ctrlCaribbeanIslands.addReview);
router.get('/traceYourTravel', ctrlCaribbeanIslands.tracetravel);


**module.exports = router;**

//controller 
module.exports.login = function (req, res) {
  res.render('index', { title: 'login'});
};

module.exports.addPost = function(req, res){
  res.render('index', { title: 'Add Post' });
};

module.exports.addChat = function(req, res){
  res.render('index', { title: 'Add Chat' });
};

module.exports.addReview = function(req, res){
  res.render('index', { title: 'Add Review' });

};
module.exports.tracetravel = function(req, res){
  res.render('index', { title: 'Trace travel' });

};
```

**app.js**

```
var createError = require('http-errors');
var express = require('express');
var handlebars = require('hbs');
var path = require('path');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var logger = require('morgan');
var hbs = require ('express-handlebars');


var indexRouter = require('./app_server/routes/index');
var usersRouter = require('./app_server/routes/users');

var app = express();

app.engine('hbs', hbs ({extname: 'hbs',defaultLayout: 'layout', layoutsDir:__dirname + '/app_server/views'}));
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'app_server','views'));
app.set('view engine', 'hbs');
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());

app.use('/', indexRouter);
app.use('/users', usersRouter);

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
  next(createError(404));
});

// error handler
app.use(function (err, req, res, next) {
  // set locals, only providing error in development
  res.locals.message = err.message;
  res.locals.error = req.app.get('env') === 'development' ? err : {};

  // render the error page
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render('error');
});

module.exports = app;
```

Comment: Did to try to set the path directly by declaring something like "C:/Users/Admin/layout.hbs"?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to change default layout in express using handlebars?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26871522/how-to-change-default-layout-in-express-using-handlebars)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Zrushb Sorry, my bad, it's with app.set, not use. The code should look like this:

```
const express = require("express"),
hbs = require("hbs"),
mongoose = require("mongoose")
bodyParser = require("body-[arser")

var app = express()
//In ** your database if you need any
mongoose.connect("mongodb:localhost:27017/**")


app.set("view engine", "hbs")

//To get or post

app.set("view engine", "hbs") //Engine HBS
app.set("views", __dirname +"/views") //Folder views (templates)
app.use(express.static("public")) //Public is static (to get .js, images and .css)
app.use('/css',express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public/stylesheets'))); //Css folder specified (NOT WORKING)
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false})) //Post Body Parser
app.use(bodyParser.json()) //Parser for JSON files
app.use(cookieParser())
hbs.registerPartials(__dirname+ "views/partials")


app.get("/" //etc)

app.post(//etc)
```

Comment: Ofc you dont need bodyParser if you are not using Post method, same goes with mongoose I just took it from a snippet I have

Answer (score 0):

I think express no longer contains handlebars in it, I'd reccomend to download HBS with npm and then require it  `var hbs = require('hbs')`

Then set the view engine to hbs like this -> `app.use("view engine", "hbs")`

Try that instead of requiring it from express-handlebars, it has worked for me so far.

Comment: @ David Bros, I have done the steps above, I have installed hbs with npm after install I looked within dependencies and ""hbs": "^4.0.1"," installed successfully.  I started to implement var hbs = require('hbs') and app.use("view engine", "hbs").. I begin to run the code now i see  errors in the terminal stating    TypeError: hbs is not a function
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Sue\myCommunityFinal2\app.js:17:19)
    at Module._compile (module.js:653:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:664:10)

Answer (score 0):

```js
app.engine('hbs', hbs({
  extname: 'hbs',
  defaultLayout: 'layout',
  layoutsDir:__dirname + '/app_server/views'
}));
```

change `hbs` to `hbs.engine` like this:

```js
app.engine('hbs', hbs.engine({
  extname: 'hbs',
  defaultLayout: 'layout',
  layoutsDir:__dirname + '/app_server/views'
}));
```

Answer (score 0):

// view engine setup

1. `app.engine('hbs',hbs({extname:'hbs',defaultLayout:'layout',layoutDir:__dirname+'/views/layouts/'}));`
2. `app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));`
3. `app.set('view engine', 'hbs');`

change (01) line like this (hbs to hbs.engine):

`app.engine('hbs',hbs.engine({extname:'hbs',defaultLayout:'layout',layoutDir:__dirname+'/views/layouts/'}));`

Answer (score 0):

change that
app.engine('hbs', *hbs*({ extname: 'hbs', defaultLayout: 'layout', layoutsDir: __dirname + '/views/layout/', partialsDir: __dirname + '/views/partials/' })); to
app.engine('hbs', *hbs.engine*({ extname: 'hbs', defaultLayout: 'layout', layoutsDir: __dirname + '/views/layout/', partialsDir: __dirname + '/views/partials/' }));

ie cahnage hbs to hbs.engine

app.engine('hbs', hbs.engine({ extname: 'hbs', defaultLayout: 'layout', layoutsDir: __dirname + '/views/layout/', partialsDir: __dirname + '/views/partials/' }));
this is better for latest versions

Comment: Hi, please read [formatting help](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)