# Different css files from public/ folder for different .hbs files in views directory using main.hbs

Tags: css, handlebars.js

I have a main.hbs file which holds my imported js and css. This works for my index.hbs but my other hbs files such as category.hbs require different (conflicting) .css files. How can I create more hbs files like main.hbs for holding these references pointing to the javascripts and stylesheets?

Right now, I have been just adding the requisite files on the top and bottom of my individual .hbs files.

```html
<!-- At the top of category.js -->


<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../public/styles/category.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../public/styles/category_responsive.css">
```

Answer (score 1):

Use different layout file.

main.hbs is your index.hbs

Create new layout file main2.hbs for your other .hbs files that has conflicting css files. main2.hbs will have your conflicting css files in there.

Your route file will call the main2.hbs layout file

> res.render('view', { title: 'my other page', layout: 'main2' });

So the pages that has conflicting css file, use the second layout. This will mean you have 2 layout files that uses different css files.

More info [How to change default layout in express using handlebars?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26871522/how-to-change-default-layout-in-express-using-handlebars)